# Convert date and time based on GMT

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I need help in converting date and time using GMT time. Currently I'm using `Convertdatetime` using timezone, but I need to convert the date and time based on GMT selected from the below dropdown using only GMT and the `now()` function is used for storing date and time into [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) (server time)?

For example (2012/08/11 18:45:00)
Afghanistan
to  Saturday, August 11, 2012  5:43 PM

Andorra
3:16 PM
Saturday, August 11, 2012

```
<option value="Afghanistan">(GMT+4:30) Afghanistan</option>
<option value="Andorra">(GMT +1:00) Andorra</option>
<option value="United Arab Emirates">(GMT +04:00) United Arab Emirates</option>
<option value="Antigua and Barbuda">(GMT +04:00) Antigua and Barbuda</option>


function Convertdatetime($gmttime,$timezoneRequired)
{
    $system_timezone = date_default_timezone_get();

    $local_timezone = $timezoneRequired;
    date_default_timezone_set($local_timezone);
    $local = date("Y-m-d h:i:s A");

    date_default_timezone_set("GMT");
    $gmt = date("Y-m-d h:i:s A");

    date_default_timezone_set($system_timezone);
    $diff = (strtotime($gmt) - strtotime($local));

    $date = new DateTime($gmttime);
    $date->modify("+$diff seconds");
    $timestamp = $date->format("m-d-Y H:i:s");
    return $timestamp;
}
ConvertLocalTimezoneToGMT('2012-08-11 17:24:00.000','Asia/Calcutta');
```

> Output: 11-08-2012 11:54:00 ||  GMT = IST-5.5

Answer (score 1):

To change your timezones, you just have to use the setter *[setTimezone](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php)*:

```
$systemTz = new DateTimezone($system_timezone);
$gmt = new DateTimeZone('GMT');
$serverTz = new dateTimezone($server_timezone);
$dateServer = new DateTime($sqlResult['date_column'],$serverTz);
$gmt = clone $dateServer;
$gmt->setTimezone($gmt);
$dateSyst = clone DateServer;
$dateSyst->setTimezone($systemTz);
```

Then you can format them as you want.

Answer (score 0):

The following code can give you the difference in seconds for different time zones:

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone("Asia/Karachi");
$offset = $timezone->getOffset(new DateTime("now"));
```

Replace `Asia/Karachi` by whatever the user selected than simply add these seconds to the time

> DateTimeZone::getOffset — Returns the timezone offset from GMT

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php

Comment: @Muhammed Ahmad Zafer: Thanks for replying, but i have already got gmt value from dropdown, based on gmt value i need convert to  dateand time for the country